# Splitting multi-band tiff images and processing each single-band image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, tiff, qgis

I have a tiff image with 2 bands that is not readable by OpenCV functions imread() and imreadmulti().  I can view the image in QGIS and the image is not binary. I've managed to extract the bands by using ImageMagick software (magick convert name.tif name%d.tif). But, the extracted single-band images are binary (pixels values are either 0 or 255).

I've also tried gdal_translate (gdal_translate -b bandNumber in.tif out.tif), but the single-band images are binary again. My goal is to access one of the two bands and change its pixels values by OpenCV (map them to [0,1]) and ignore the second band.

I know for a fact (according to QGIS) that pixel values of each band vary from 0 to 255 and they are not binary but when I split the bands and save them as separate images, they are binary.

Comment: And where is this image please?

Comment: Hi Mark, I was not allowed to post the image but I managed to solve the problem. OpenCV can't read images in float. gdal_translate was splitting the bands correctly but Windows photo viewer showed them in binary, I noticed that QGIS shows them correctly. I ended up using GDAL in C++ instead of OpenCV.